# ReferenceError: Cannot access before initialization. Is this circular dependency?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

In `index.js`, I have:

```
console.log("index.js loading...");
import express from "express";
export const app = express();

import { router as login } from "./login.js";
app.use("/login", login);
```

In `login.js` I have:

```
console.log("login.js loading...");
import express from "express";
import { app } from "./index.js";
import passport from "passport";

app.use(passport.initialize());
```

When trying to run, I get a `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'app' before initialization` at the last statement in `login.js`. The line "login.js loading..." is printed, but not "index.js loading...".

While the two files are importing from one another, isn't `app` fully initialized in the third line in `index.js`? How is the order of loading determined? Would the error be there if `index.js` was loaded first?